# Reading binary data without reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, casting, binary

Just because I've never read binary files before I wrote a program that reads binary STL files. I use `ifstream`s read member that takes a char* a parameter. To cast my struct to a char* I use a reinterpret_cast. But as far as I remember every book about C++ I read said something like "don't use reinterpret_cast except you have to". What would be a better way read binary data, not necessarily direct, but at last into a struct and without reinterpret_cast?

The main function:

```
std::ifstream in (cmdline[1].c_str(), std::ios::binary);

in.seekg(80, std::ifstream::beg); //skip header

int numTriangle;
in.read (reinterpret_cast<char*>(&numTriangle), sizeof(int)); //determine number of triangles
//create triangle data type and read data
triangle* t = new triangle();
for (int i = 0; i < numTriangle; ++i)  {
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(t), triangle::size);
    std::cout << *t;  // there's an opertor<< for triangle
}
delete t;

in.close(); //close file read from
```

And the triangle struct

```
//attempt to get the right size of a class without structure padding
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)

//standard STL triangle data structure
struct triangle {
public:
    float n[3]; //normals, 4*3=12 bytes

    float x[3]; //first point of the triangle, 4*3=12 bytes
    float y[3]; //second point of the triangle, 4*3=12 bytes
    float z[3]; //third point of the triangle, 4*3=12 bytes

    long int a; //attributes, 2 bytes

    static const int size = 12+12+12+12+2; //sum of member variables
    //static const int size = sizeof(n) + sizeof(x) + sizeof(y) + sizeof(z) + sizeof(a);
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

(Extra question: #pragma pack(1) doesn't work with cygwins g++-4. How can I determine the size of the struct?)

Comment: If you are reading/writing binary data it is a good idea to use reinterpret_cast. This is because the code is inherently non portable and thus reinterpret_cast is a good way of self documenting the code to indicate the code is non portable. Note: There is nothing wrong with your code. It is non portable because of the way C/C++ define the basic types and their layout (which can be different across hardware/OS/Compiler/Compiler flags).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, that code looks fine. You are even caring about the padding issue. I don't see how you can avoid casting here. You can do this sequence:

```
static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(t))
```

But really, i don't do that in my code. It's just a more noisy way of doing a direct reinterpret_cast to `char*`. (See [casting via void* instead of using reinterpret_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863069/casting-via-void-instead-of-using-reinterpret-cast) ).

---

The struct size can be determined using `sizeof`. You just have to initialize the `static` member out of the class inside the `.cpp` (however, then the compiler doesn't know the value of `::size` anymore and can't inline it).
Alternatively, you can write it as a static inline member function. In its body, the class type is considered complete and `sizeof (triangle)` is allowed. Or you can just use `sizeof` like you have in the comment, but use the type and not the members (referring to nonstatic members that way is allowed only in C++0x) :

```
//standard STL triangle data structure
struct triangle {
public:
    float n[3]; //normals, 4*3=12 bytes

    float x[3]; //first point of the triangle, 4*3=12 bytes
    float y[3]; //second point of the triangle, 4*3=12 bytes
    float z[3]; //third point of the triangle, 4*3=12 bytes

    long int a; //attributes, 2 bytes

    static int size() { return sizeof(triangle); } // this way
    static const int size = sizeof(float[3])*4 + sizeof(long int); // or this way
};
```

However, the second way is not nice since you can easily forget updating it when you add a member.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to delete the second line, it was late that day I wrote this. However, my cygwins gcc/g++/... seems broken, neither sizeof, nor sizeof+pragma pack, nor sizeof __attribute__((pack)) works.

Comment: Note that doing state serialization like this is inherently unportable - trying to read a file on a different architecure (or even the same one with a different compiler) may yield a garbage data restoration. Also I haven't seen a system where long was two bytes in a very long time - most likely it will be four or eight bytes spending on processor and compiler settings. Edit: What do you mean that those things don't work? Did you try removing the pragma pack and the static size function suggested?

Comment: In fact, `long` *must* be greater than 2 bytes on any system that has 8bit bytes.

Comment: You could always move the calculation of `size` into a separate traits class. Then you get the best of both worlds and remove the concern of serialization from the class itself.

Comment: Yes, this `long` was the missing link. Of course it should have been a `short int`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Extra question: Take a look at `__attribute__((packed))`.

Answer (score -2):

Using streams for file i/o (esp. binary) is just nasty in my opinion. I'd rather just use the old C functions like fopen and fread if I were you.

Also, memory mapping of a file is a technique which is given too little love, IMO. I don't know of any standard/portable libraries that support it, but if you're on Windows I suggest checking [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx)

Comment: Any substantiation at all? Why are the standard C++ functions "nasty"? What do they lack? What do the ancient C versions do better? I'm very sceptical. I've had no trouble using C++ fstreams to read files over carefully mapped structs and do all kinds of bit-accurate stuff. Their benefits of OO, RAII, exception handling, and presumably more, are very significant. This is more like an opinionated rant than a usable answer.