# Convert struct into bytes

Tags: c++

How would you convert any struct into byte array on processors with little-endian?

Comment: expand upon your request please - and note that your answer will be extremely processor architecture dependent

Comment: What is the addressing unit for little endian?  What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a `char*` to access any type of object in C++, so:

```
struct S
{
    int a;
    int b;
    // etc.
};

S my_s;

char* my_s_bytes = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&my_s);

// or, if you prefer static_cast:
char* my_s_bytes = static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(&my_s));
```

(There is at least [some debate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863069/casting-via-void-instead-of-using-reinterpret-cast) over the correctness of the `reinterpret_cast` vs. the `static_cast`; in practice it doesn't really matter--both should yield the same result)

Comment: :-) too many language improvements now on C++.  Whereas before, this would suffice: `char* b = (char*)&my_s;` Perhaps if i learn C++ again, I'll read something about those cast constructs first.

Comment: @Michael:  That C-style cast is the same as the `reinterpret_cast` in this case, because no combination of `static_cast` and `const_cast` is valid.  Using the C++ style casts guarantees you get the cast you intend; the C-style cast basically just tries a sequence of five different types of casts until it finds one that works.

Comment: The answer is right given the struct you specified. However, throw some shorts, large_integers, or character data in there and it is horribly wrong.

Comment: @T.E.D.:  "horribly wrong" depends entirely on how the char array is to be used.  Certainly there are times where this is not the answer, but frequently this is good enough.  The requirements were certainly underspecified.

Answer (score 10):

I like to use a `union`:

```
typedef struct b {
  unsigned int x;
  unsigned int y;
} b_s;

typedef union a {
  b_s my_struct;
  char ary[sizeof(b_s)];
} a_u;
```

Comment: Why not just `ary[sizeof(b)]`?

Comment: This is the way

Comment: @RobKennedy Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/19577625/8628293 , nothing is late :)

Comment: Thank you, @Anlgrses, but my question from 13 years prior wasn't "Why a union instead of just a standalone array?" My question was "Why sizeof the typedef instead of simply sizeof the struct type?"

Answer (score 10):

```
(char*)&someStruct
```

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to do? If you're trying to serialize the struct so you can save it to a file or pass it in a message, you're better off using a tool designed for that like [boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

If you just want an array of bytes you could `reinterpret_cast<char*>` as others have mentioned, or do:

```
MyStruct s;
char [] buffer = new char[sizeof(s)];
memcpy(&buffer, &s, sizeof(s));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would peer into the `void*`.

```
struct gizmo 
{
//w/e
};

//stuff

gizmo *G = new gizmo;

void* bytearray = (void*)G;
```

How your struct gets packed is ambiguous and depends on compiler, ABI, and CPU. You'll have to figure that out from your manuals & some assembly reading.

Comment: You can't access bytes through a void*

Comment: Since you cannot dereference a void*, you can't access whatever it points to(perhaps bar using memcpy, in which case a intermediate void* isn't needed) foo[0]; is a compiler error if foo is a void*. Use an unsigned char* to access individual bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with all of these answers is that you can't really do dumb byte swapping without knowing something about the data you are swapping. Character data does *not* get swapped. 64-bit integers need a different kind of swapping depending on exactly how the two processors in question implemented them.