# C++ Push Multiple Types onto Vector

Tags: c++, memory-management, types, vector

**Note:** I know similar questions to this have been asked on SO before, but I did not find them helpful or very clear.

**Second note:** For the scope of this project/assignment, I'm trying to avoid third party libraries, such as Boost.

I am trying to see if there is a way I can have a single vector hold multiple types, in each of its indices. For example, say I have the following code sample:

```
vector<something magical to hold various types> vec;
int x = 3;
string hi = "Hello World";
MyStruct s = {3, "Hi", 4.01};

vec.push_back(x);
vec.push_back(hi);
vec.push_back(s);
```

I've heard `vector<void*>` could work, but then it gets tricky with memory allocation and then there is always the possibility that certain portions in nearby memory could be unintentionally overridden if a value inserted into a certain index is larger than expected.

In my actual application, I know what *possible* types may be inserted into a vector, but these types do not all derive from the same super class, and there is no guarantee that all of these types will be pushed onto the vector or in what order.

Is there a way that I can **safely** accomplish the objective I demonstrated in my code sample?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: @chris Sorry I wasn't clear. For the scope of this project/assignment, I'm trying to avoid third party libraries. I've updated my question.

Comment: Well, I don't know how well it'll work, but you can have a structure with a `type` member and a union of all of the possible types.

Comment: If you are mandating you cannot *know* what is actually being pushed can we assume this vector doesn't *own* anything besides pointers? Without some way of establishing type-info at the owner-level, you're somewhat screwed in properly managing cleanup or erasure. A struct with a pointer + destructor reference is conceivable, but at that time you have to start asking yourself wth is the real data model being serviced here?

Comment: Do you actually want completely random data, or do these have some sort of relationship? If there's some sort of type hierarchy, you can store a pointer to the more generic type they all share, and you can use `shared_ptr` to make the memory less messy.

Comment: @BrendanLong Assuming that this vector would be returned from a member function, are pointers like you are talking about really possible?

Comment: Reading your question closer. It looks like you know the domain of what *can* be pushed, and it is finite, just not rooted in a common base, correct ?

Comment: You need to implement your own variant type. Which like @chris said is just a union and a type id.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, you are correct. Also note that this vector would be returned from a member function.

Comment: Then I concur with Nick and chris. You effectively need to define your own variant wrapper, which will include type id info and proper access to the appropriate type.

Comment: Try to comprehend the reasoning [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23304/High-Performance-Heterogeneous-Container) and here you are - a heterogeneous container. In case you need really "any" type, read in "beyond the standard library" on how any comes around, or try the unsafe way - of void* + management

Comment: I don't see how the data being returned from a member function would have any effect on how you implement this.

Comment: @WhozCraig Hmm... sounds time consuming, especially since the vector will have so many diverse types. So, basically, this will be just a wrapper class to encapsulate the various types?

Comment: Can you just clarify *why* you want to put many unrelated types into the same `vector`? Sometimes a little context will let us provide a better C++ language answer.

Comment: @spryno724 yes, and if you want to see how rich even seemingly simple ones can get, see [variant_t](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k74e1xsh(v=vs.80).aspx), which wraps the OLE/COM VARIANT type for Microsoft Windows. Hopefully you don't need to go that deep.

Comment: @MarkB The actual application is intended to return data from an MS SQL query. The types from each attribute in a tuple, obviously, may be mapped to various C++ types, and the vector is an attempt to mimic the structure of the data returned from the query in C++;

Comment: @spryno724 Is this on a Windows platform? (I ask after seeing your MSSQL reference, which I realize is on server-side, but had to ask.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to do that, you'll definitely need a wrapper class to somehow conceal the type information of your objects from the vector.

It's probably also good to have this class throw an exception when you try to get Type-A back when you have previously stored a Type-B into it.

Here is part of the Holder class from one of my projects. You can probably start from here.

**Note: due to the use of unrestricted unions, this only works in C++11.** More information about this can be found here: [What are Unrestricted Unions proposed in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548636/what-are-unrestricted-unions-proposed-in-c0x)

```
class Holder {
public:
    enum Type {
        BOOL,
        INT,
        STRING,
        // Other types you want to store into vector.
    };

    template<typename T>
    Holder (Type type, T val);

    ~Holder () {
        // You want to properly destroy
        // union members below that have non-trivial constructors
    }

    operator bool () const {
        if (type_ != BOOL) {
           throw SomeException();
        }
        return impl_.bool_;
    }
    // Do the same for other operators
    // Or maybe use templates?

private:
    union Impl {
        bool   bool_;
        int    int_;
        string string_;

        Impl() { new(&string_) string; }
    } impl_;

    Type type_;

    // Other stuff.
};
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't put `std::string` in a union because of `9.5/1` which says you can't do that if it has a non-trivial constructor, copy constructor, destructor, or copy assignment operator.

Comment: you can now in c++11, which has all the goodness :p You can refer to it at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Unrestricted_unions).

Comment: You should probably note that this is a C++11-only solution in your answer then, as well as noting that you'll have to use placement new and explicit destruction to use the `string` member safely.

Comment: modified my answer to state it is C++11-only :-)

Comment: Did someone profile this code? This solution seems clean but is it faster or slower than the traditional polymorphism + virtual or dynamic_cast<>?

Answer (score 22):

The objects hold by the `std::vector<T>` need to be of a homogenous type. If you need to put objects of different type into one vector you need somehow erase their type and make them all look similar. You could use the moral equivalent of `boost::any` or `boost::variant<...>`. The idea of `boost::any` is to encapsulate a type hierarchy, storing a pointer to the base but pointing to a templatized derived. A very rough and incomplete outline looks something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

class any
{
private:
    struct base {
        virtual ~base() {}
        virtual base* clone() const = 0;
    };
    template <typename T>
    struct data: base {
        data(T const& value): value_(value) {}
        base* clone() const { return new data<T>(*this); }
        T value_;
    };
    base* ptr_;
public:
    template <typename T> any(T const& value): ptr_(new data<T>(value)) {}
    any(any const& other): ptr_(other.ptr_->clone()) {}
    any& operator= (any const& other) {
        any(other).swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }
    ~any() { delete this->ptr_; }
    void swap(any& other) { std::swap(this->ptr_, other.ptr_); }

    template <typename T>
    T& get() {
        return dynamic_cast<data<T>&>(*this->ptr_).value_;
    }
};

int main()
{
    any a0(17);
    any a1(3.14);
    try { a0.get<double>(); } catch (...) {}
    a0 = a1;
    std::cout << a0.get<double>() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: +1, good answer.  Though remember in data, clone() should be `data<T>* clone() const` as it is covariant :)  But this is arguably the better answer than the accepted answer.

Comment: Having to know the type to fetch the data makes this solution unhelpful for many applications - i.e. using a0.get<double>(). Why not just use a void pointer if we are assuming we know the types?

Comment: @MatthaeusGaiusCaesar The difference may be minor but you can check what type is actually in there, eg., using a `dynamic_cast>`. You can do better if you are so inclined, eg., by dispatching the type check into a `virtual` function yielding a `std::type_info const&`. The Boost `any` or `std::any` (added with C++17) do effectively that and it isn’t hard to add to the short demo implementation. The code is just a basic draft and the answer says so. To make it nice you’d need to add things - or use `std::any` which didn’t exist when the answer was written.

Answer (score 9):

As suggested you can use various forms of unions, variants, etc.  Depending on what you want to do with your stored objects, external polymorphism could do exactly what you want, ***if you can define all necessary operations in a base class interface***.

Here's an example if all we want to do is print the objects to the console:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class any_type
{
public:
   virtual ~any_type() {}
   virtual void print() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class concrete_type : public any_type
{
public:
   concrete_type(const T& value) : value_(value)
   {}

   virtual void print()
   {
      std::cout << value_ << '\n';
   }
private:
   T value_;
};

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::unique_ptr<any_type>> v(2);

   v[0].reset(new concrete_type<int>(99));
   v[1].reset(new concrete_type<std::string>("Bottles of Beer"));

   for(size_t x = 0; x < 2; ++x)
   {
      v[x]->print();
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to have, rather than `print()` a `T get()` function where you can somehow to `v[x]::T result = v[x].get()`?

Comment: Recommend bolding this part of your description "if you can define all necessary operations in a base class interface", this is vital else the solution will not work. It is worth noting that the same applies to member variables?