# Vector that can have 3 different data types C++

Tags: c++, vector, polymorphism

I'm trying to make a vector in C++ that can store 3 different data types. I do not want to use the boost library.
Something like:

```
vector<type1, type2, type3> vectorName;
```

Do I need to make a template? And if yes how would I do that?

Comment: You would probably need some type of wrapper class/container to hold references to the different types. A similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461869/c-push-multiple-types-onto-vector)

Comment: See [`tuple`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/), perhaps. Vectors (aka lists) are sequences of one or more *homogeneous* items. Tuples are finite (and fixed-sized) collections of possible heterogeneous members.

Comment: Do you want to have a vector whose elements each contain all 3 types? Or a vector that can contain one type or the others?

Comment: "I do not want to use the boost library." That's a shame, since it has [exactly what you want](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/variant.html).

Comment: Depending on exactly what you need, you might consider writing a POD struct to aggregate your types together. Then, just make a vector of those.

Answer (score 38):

EDIT: as of C++17, the standard library now includes the class template [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), which is quite similar to pre-existing solutions in boost. `variant` is a type-safe alternative to unions that allows multiple types to be joined using an "or" relationship, e.g., an `std::variant<type1, type2, typ3>` contains either a `type1` OR a `type2` OR a `type3.` It can be composed with `std::vector` to yield exactly what you've described:

```
std::vector<std::variant<type1, type2, type3>> vectorName;
```

However, `std::variant` does introduce some restrictions. For example, it cannot hold reference or array types, and the underlying type (i.e. `type1` or `type2`) can only be accessed by template code. If `std::variant` does not permit the specific behavior you need, keep reading for a more complicated but more versatile approach that also has the benefit of working in any version of C++.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

The easiest way to store multiple types in the same vector is to make them subtypes of a parent class, wrapping your desired types in classes if they aren't classes already.

```
class Parent {
  // Anything common to the types should be declared here, for instance:
  void print() { // Make this virtual if you want subclasses to override it
     std::cout << "Printing!";
  }

  virtual ~Parent(); //virtual destructor to ensure our subclasses are correctly deallocated
};

class Type1 : public Parent {
    void type1method();
};

class Type2 : public Parent {
    void type2Method();
};


class Type3 : public Parent {
    void type3Method();
};
```

You can then create a vector of `Parent` pointers that can store pointers to the child types:

```
std::vector<Parent*> vec;

vec.push_back(new Type1);
vec.push_back(new Type2);
vec.push_back(new Type3);
```

When accessing elements directly from the vector, you'll only be able to use members that belong to `Parent`. For instance, you can write:

```
vec[0]->print();
```

But not:

```
vec[0]->type1Method();
```

As the element type has been declared as `Parent*` and the `Parent` type has no member named `type1Method`.

If you need to access the subtype-specific members, you can convert the `Parent` pointers to subtype pointers like so:

```
Parent *p = vec[0];

Type1 *t1 = nullptr;
Type2 *t2 = nullptr;
Type3 *t3 = nullptr;

if (t1 = dynamic_cast<Type1*>(p)) {
    t1->type1Method();
}
else if (t2 = dynamic_cast<Type2*>(p)) {
    t2->type2Method();
}
else if (t3 = dynamic_cast<Type3*>(p)) {
    t3->type3Method();
}
```

Although it's generally considered a better idea to avoid this kind of explicit type-branching and instead rely on virtual methods.

Be sure to delete the pointers before removing them from the vector if you use dynamic allocation, as I did in the example above. Alternatively, use smart pointers (probably `std::unique_ptr`) and let your memory take care of itself:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent>> vec;
```

Comment: You didn't delete anything. Why not use a vector of unique_ptr so it deletes it automatically? Parent needs a virtual destructor.

Comment: @NeilKirk Right, forgot about the virtual destructor. I'll mention smart pointers as well.

Comment: Ok I can add different types to my vector but I can't access the specific methods in the types. How can I access those different methods? For example if I want to call vec[i].print(); Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @JonathanForney Any methods that can be applied to all three types should go in the parent type. I'll add an example.

Answer (score 8):

> I'm trying to make a vector in C++ that can store 3 different data types.

The answer here really depends on the particular use case:

1. If the objects are somehow connected and similar in some fashion - create a base class and derive all the classes from it, then make the vector store `unique_ptr`s to the parent class (see **ApproachingDarknessFish** s answer for details),
2. If the objects are all of fundamental (so built-in) types - use an `union` that groups the types and define a `vector<yourUnionType>`,
3. If the objects are of unknown type, but you're sure they share a similiar interface,  create a base class, and derive a templated child class from it (`template <typename T> class container: public parent{};`), and create a `vector<unique_ptr<parent>>` like in the first case,
4. If the objects are of types that for some reason cannot be connected (so for example the `vector` stores `int`, `std::string`, and `yourType`), connect them via an `union`, like in *2*. Or - even better...

...if you have time and want to learn something - look how `boost::any` is implemented and try implementing it yourself, if you really don't want to use the library itself. It's not as hard as it may seem.

Comment: Why the restriction in option 2?

Comment: @MSalters because I strongly believe that if they're not - deriving a base class is a more object-oriented solution. Also - using unions in a `vector` isn't particulary convenient - you have to additionally store a secondary vector which would contain the type that every union stores, so you access it properly and don't get junk.

Comment: The need for a vector of discriminants is needed for fundamental types too, so that's no reason to make a distinction. And as you note, the lack of a common base class is a real problem, so why not stick with option 2 in that case instead of the ugly hack in 4?

Comment: @MSalters to be honest you're right. I'll edit option 4. Guess I overthought it.

Answer (score 4):

you could use std::any, store your objects in the vector as any and when you pull them out use type() == typeid(mytype)

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any

This is only for C++17 onwards though.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a vector? You might just consider a linked list of generic type, then iterate through that list, use typeid() to figure out the data type of the node and pull the data with a node.get() function.