# Pointers to vectors of derived a derived class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I'm trying to have a vector of pointers to vectors of differents classes and where each classes is derived from a same base class.

My code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

class A 
{ 
public: 
    A() { std::cout << "A constructor.\n"; } 
    virtual ~A() { std::cout << "A destructor\n"; } 

    virtual void iAm() { std::cout << "I am A.\n"; } 
}; 

class B : public A 
{ 
public: 
    B() { std::cout << "B constructor.\n"; } 
    ~B() { std::cout << "B destructor.\n"; } 

    virtual void iAm() { std::cout << "I am B.\n"; } 
private:
    std::string s;
}; 

class C : public A 
{ 
public: 
    C() { std::cout << "C constructor.\n"; } 
    ~C() { std::cout << "C destructor.\n"; } 

    virtual void iAm() { std::cout << "I am C.\n"; } 
private:
    std::string s;
    int n;
}; 

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::vector<A>*> vect;
    vect.resize(3);

    vect[0]=new std::vector<A>;
    vect[1]=(std::vector<A>*) new std::vector<B>;
    vect[2]=(std::vector<A>*) new std::vector<C>;

    vect[0]->push_back(A());
    vect[0]->push_back(A());
    vect[1]->push_back(B(methods are A methods));
    vect[1]->push_back(B());
    vect[2]->push_back(C());
    vect[2]->push_back(C());

    (*vect[0])[0].iAm();
    (*vect[0])[1].iAm();
    (*vect[1])[0].iAm();
    (*vect[1])[1].iAm();
    (*vect[2])[0].iAm();
    (*vect[2])[1].iAm();

}
```

But the execution give me:

```
A constructor.

A destructor.

A constructor.

A destructor.

A destructor.

A constructor.

B constructor.

B destructor.

A destructor.

A constructor.

B constructor.

A destructor.

B destructor.

A destructor.

A constructor.

C constructor.

C destructor.

A destructor.

A constructor.

C constructor.

A destructor.

C destructor.

A destructor.

I am A.

I am A.

I am A.

I am A.

I am A.

I am A.
```

I don't understand why, although I create `B` and `C` objects, the call of the method `iAm()` call the `A's` `iAm()`. The call of `B` and `C` `iAm()` must call the versions of `B` and `C` because the constructor are `B` and `C` and because I just cast pointers to the vectors, not the elements in the vector.

What I didn't understand about this?

Thanks You.

Comment: Applying c-style cast `= (std::vector<A>*) new std::vector<B>;` breaks type checking. You can not assign a `std::vector<B> *` to `std::vector<A> *` for a reason.

Comment: This is kind of baffling: `(std::vector<A>*) new std::vector<B>;` You are telling the compile to pretend a pointer to one type is a pointer to an unrelated type. I can't see how you could expect sane results from that. Honestly, how do you have any clue what result that will produce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is that you assume that `std::vector<B>` is compatible with `std::vector<A>` because B is derived from A. This is not the case. The inheritance relationship between A and B does not translate to an inheritance relationship between `std::vector<A>` and `std::vector<B>`. You had to use C-style casts to silence the compiler's error messages, but that doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out this question:
[Vector that can have 3 different data types C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26208918/vector-that-can-have-3-different-data-types-c)

Here's an example how your code could work:

```
std::vector<std::vector<A*>*> vect;
//you can also do vect.resize(3) and then write something like vect[0] = new std::vector<A*>;
vect.push_back(new std::vector<A*>);
vect[0]->push_back(new A());
vect.push_back(new vector<A*>);
vect[1]->push_back(new B());

(*vect[0])[0]->iAm();
(*vect[1])[0]->iAm();
```

This will print:

A constructor.

A constructor.

B constructor.

"I am A."

"I am B."

Also, consider using smart pointers.