# declare a c++ vector that can contain all data types defined in a namespace

Tags: c++, vector, header, header-files

i have a file called "dtypes.h", that contains some definitions for some numerical data types.

```
namespace dtypes {
  typedef signed short int int16;      
  // ... some other dtypes
}
```

i also have another file where i want to create a vector that can contain all this data types (and other vectors). I figured out something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include "dtypes.h"

std::vector<std::variant<\* ??? *\>> content;
```

I really don't know what to place instead of "???", without having to list all the different data types (without doing `std::vector<std::variant<dtypes::int16, dtypes::int32 \*...*\>> content;`)
I found some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26208918/vector-that-can-have-3-different-data-types-c), but it is not exactly what i want.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/26208947/7611357. You have a good detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26208947/7611357)

Comment: the q&a you link has lots of answers that could apply here. You sould explain why you dont want them, otherwise we will just repeat here what has already been said there

Comment: Why? This question is example of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). In C++ there is no way to reflect all symbols in namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to make the list right *there*, but you need to make the list *somewhere*. There's no way avoiding writing the list explicitly.

Like one of the answers in the linked question suggests, you could use a vector of `std::any` to store objects of *any* type. With the obvious drawback of losing the features of a variant type.

---

Regarding `typedef signed short int int16;`, I suggest taking a look at the standard `<cstdint>` header. It contains aliases for fixed width integers. There's no need to duplicate that effort (unless you need to support pre-C++11 and cannot use open source libraries).

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, is <cstdint> actually safe to use? I mean is it always accessible from any version >c++11?

Comment: @Giuppox Yes, it is.

Comment: `<cstdint>` is a C++ header file.  It's perfectly cromulent to use in C++ code.

Comment: hi, i tried using `std::any` (`std::vector<std::any> content;`), but even though I have required the `#require <any>` module there seems to be no `any` variable in the std namespace.

Comment: @Giuppox What is `#require`?

Comment: sorry, i meant `#include`, lately i have nodejs spinning in my head

Comment: @Giuppox std::any was introduced in C++17. Perhaps you're compiling for an older standard.

Comment: thats strange, i am having the same problem with `std::variant`. And i am sure i am compiling over C++98, and actually including it doesn't throws any error, doesn't it mean that the header file has been found?

Comment: @Giuppox Well, there's the problem. There weren't `std::variant` nor `std::any` in C++98.

Comment: Oww, that's a mess, i really thought C++98 was an earlier version that C++17. What is the newer version then?

Comment: @Giuppox C++98 was the first standard version of C++. It's not newer.

Answer (score 1):

You can store all the items using a `std::vector`, by submitting `std::any` as a template parameter to the `std::variant`. It would look something like this,

```cpp
std::vector<std::variant<std::any>> arr;
arr.push_back("Hello World");
arr.push_back(10);
arr.push_back(10.0f);
arr.push_back(10.0);

auto any = std::get<std::any>(arr[0]);
auto pTypeName = any.type().name();    // You can get the name of the type to match and cast if your not sure about the index.
std::string str = std::any_cast<const char*>(any);
```

Now you can use this if using `std::variant` is mandatory. If not you can use a `std::vector` of `std::any` as the other answer stated.

Comment: you arent answering the question.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Woops I answered the title. My bad.

Comment: hi, why the first line of your code `std::vector<std::variant<std::any>> arr;` shouldn't it be `std::vector<variant<std::any>> arr;`? it is throwing `error: no member named 'variant' in namespace 'std'`

Comment: @Giuppox `variant` is part of the STL which means that is must be inside the `std` namespace.

Comment: shouldn't i include it by doing `#include <variant>`?

Comment: @Giuppox Yes you should. If not how will the compiler know about the object?

Comment: it seems like also when i include it it is available like `variant` but not as `std::variant`

Comment: @Giuppox That seems strange.. What C++ version are you working with?

Comment: i am using C++98. Note that `#include <variant>
int main() {
  std::variant<int, float> x;
}` doesn't works and throws `error: no member named 'variant' in namespace 'std'`. Any suggestion??

Comment: @Giuppox `std::variant` and `st::any` was added in C++17. That is the reason.