# Accessing elements in Vector of derived structs?

Tags: c++

My goal is to store elements of different data types in one vector.
A ball as well as an cuboid is an object.

```cpp
//header.h

struct Object {
};

struct Ball : Object {
  int diameter;
  int surface;
};

struct Cuboid : Object {
  int length;
  int width;
  int height;
  int surface;
};

std::vector<Object *> myObjects;
```

```cpp
//source.cpp
myObjects.push_back(new Ball);
```

Now I would like to access the members of ball by:

```cpp
myObjects[0]->diameter = 8; //not possible
```

The IDE only shows me the option accessing constructor of objects:

```cpp
myObjects[0]->Object
```

I found some useful articles:

[A true heterogenous container in c++](https://gieseanw.wordpress.com/2017/05/03/a-true-heterogeneous-container-in-c/)
[SO: Vector that can have 3 different data types C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26208918/vector-that-can-have-3-different-data-types-c)

Do I have to go this way? I really just would like to store ball and cuboid in one vector and later on access members of ball and cuboid.

Comment: "I really just would like to store ball and cuboid in one vector and later on access members of ball and cuboid." How do you know which is which?

Comment: when you decide for polymorphism you should not work against it but rather with it. Accessing a `Ball` member of a `Object*` is the opposite of polymorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to think about **why** you need to access `diameter`.

Once you figure that out, you should add a virtual member function for `Object` that would use that member. Then, you override that virtual member function in `Ball`, and use the `diameter` there.

Example:

```
struct Object {
    virtual float
    volume() const = 0;
    
    virtual ~Object() = default;
};

struct Ball : Object {
    virtual float
    volume() const override {
        float r = diameter / 2.f;
        return 4.f / 3.f * pi * r * r * r;
    }

private:
    int diameter;
};

struct Cuboid : Object {
    virtual float
    volume() const override {
        return 1.f * length * width * height;
    }

private:
    int length;
    int width;
    int height;
};
```

Use a constructor to initialise the members:

```
struct Ball : Object {
    Ball(int diameter) : diameter(diameter) {}
    // ...


std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>> myObjects;
myObjects.push_back(std::make_unique<Ball>(8));
```

---

P.S. Avoid bare owning pointers. You'll get a  memory leak or worse.

P.P.S. If you tried to delete the derived object through the base pointer, the behaviour of the program would be undefined. To avoid that, define a virtual destructor for base (as shown in my example).

P.P.P.S. Avoid dynamic_cast based polymorphism. Prefer virtual functions when possible.

Comment: `static_cast<float>(length) * width * heigth` would avoid overflow since the return type is float anyway.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Good point. I chose `1.f * ` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completion, C++ provides *dynamic casting* for use cases like that. When you have a pointer to a superclass, and need to know whether it actually points to a specific class object, you can use `dynamic_cast`:

```
myObjects.push_back(new Ball);
...
Ball * b = dynamic_cast<Ball *>(myObjects[0]); // b will point to a valid Ball or be NULL
if (b != NULL) {
    b->diameter = 8;
}
```

Of course, polymorphism is more *object centric*, but dynamic casting proves to be useful in real world programs.

---

But this can only work if at least one method is declared to be virtual in order to enable polymorphism on pointers (thanks to @AyxanHaqverdili for the *head up*):

```
struct Object {
    virtual ~Object() {};
};
```

Comment: Would dynamic cast work? Considering the objects are not polymorphic. I have to check

Comment: It doesn't work https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7oKh734oW

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: you are right. Thanks for the head up.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::variant`:

```
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

// this helper is from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit
template <class... Ts>
struct overloaded : Ts... {
  using Ts::operator()...;
};

template <class... Ts>
overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

struct Ball {
  int diameter;
  int surface;
};

struct Cuboid {
  int length;
  int width;
  int height;
  int surface;
};

using Object = std::variant<Ball, Cuboid>;

int main() {
  std::vector<Object> myObjects;
  myObjects.emplace_back(Ball{});

  std::visit(overloaded([](Ball& ball) { ball.diameter = 0; },
                        [](Cuboid& cuboid) { /* smth else */ }),
             myObjects[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case you can

1. Try using std::variant https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant
2. Try casting to the objects of interest e.g. (Ball*)myObjects[0].

Second option is not what polymorphism should look like. So you might also want to reflect on why you need such a vector in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

You can add enum to identify type

```
#include <vector>

struct Object {
    enum class Type {
        Ball,
        Cuboid
    };
    Type type;
protected:
    Object(Type t) : type(t) {}
};

struct Ball : Object {
    Ball() : Object(Object::Type::Ball) {}

    int diameter;
    int surface;
};

struct Cuboid : Object {
    Cuboid() : Object(Object::Type::Cuboid) {}

    int length;
    int width;
    int heigth;
    int surface;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Object *> myObjects;
    myObjects.push_back(new Ball);
    if (myObjects[0]->type == Object::Type::Ball)
        (static_cast<Ball *>(myObjects[0]))->diameter = 10;
    return 0;
}
```