# What is wrong with using struct for pushing multiple types in std::vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, struct

I am trying to push multiple types into same `std::vector`. For example lets say I want to push `class type1` and `class type2` into a vector.

So basically I would be able to do:

```
vec.push_back(new type1, new type2);
vec.push_back(new type1, new type2);
```

What I have in mind is to make type1 and type2 of same type by making them inherit from parent class type (but I don't have this luxury for now).

So I resort to using `struct`. So what I did was

```
struct type{ 
    type1* t1; 
    type2* t2;
};
std::vector<type> vec;
vec.push_back({new type1, new type2});
```

Do you think using struct for this is a good idea or should I use the technique that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461869/c-push-multiple-types-onto-vector) post is suggesting? My another question regarding that post why make this complex and not use just `struct` like I did?

***Edit:*** Another way is also to use `std::vector<std::pair <type1, type2>>` but since I might have type3 too so this still won't work for me.

**Edit** The `type1` and `type2` that I am talking about is `point` and `triangle`.

**Edit** **Answer From Martin in comment section** : I am now planning to use `tuple with combining with enum` see [this](http://vitiy.info/named-tuple-for-cplusplus/) for more detail.

Comment: Since you're pushing homogenous type of objects into the vector, it should "work". However, if there is a better approach would largely depend on a case to case basis. Are you able to give some more information on this scenario, as to what exactly are those two different objects that are packed into that struct?

Comment: *What I have in mind is to make type1 and type2 of same type by making them inherit from parent class type (but I don't have this luxury for now).*. We cannot talk about a *good approach* if we omit some options, especially those fundamental ones made precisely for this type of situations (Polymorphism).

Comment: Using raw pointers and the 'new' operator makes your program likely to suffer from memory leaks.  For simple objects like points and triangles, you're better off storing the objects by-value instead (e.g. std::vector<shape>, where shape is an object that can represent either a point or a triangle), but if you absolutely must dynamically allocate objects, then at least hold them with a std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr so that you won't leak them.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I was planning to use `std::unique_ptr` .. So are you saying `shape` is base class of derived class `point` and `triangle`?

Comment: You could do it that way, although if you're looking for best performance (i.e. if this isn't just an exercise in OO design principles) you might be better off with a simple, single 'shape' class that contains an array of points and a num_points_valid integer (set to 3 when representing a triangle, or set to 1 when representing a point).  That way you can store by-value (i.e. vector<shape> rather than vector<unique_ptr<shape> > ) and avoid the overhead of having to do a separate dynamic allocation for every object in the vector.

Comment: This all depends on your larger problem and how you want to access/process your various types. Why can't you use inheritance right now? What is preventing you?

Comment: @Galik after giving more thought I am not sure inheritance helps me either. I need to save point and triangle together because latter in another function  I will be using this vector to extract those point and triangle pair, then determine force applied by point upon the triangle.

Comment: @solti Then it sounds like you don't need pointers at all, just a simple aggregate type: `struct type { point p; triangle t; };`

Comment: The question you linked to is about something different - the OP there asks how to hold **any** type in the vector, you (if I understand correctly) need to hold multiple types together. In this case I see nothing wrong about simple wrapper struct.

Comment: @Galik Oh ok ... So I think I will go with pointer less `struct`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specific answer in comments: `then you could template it to the types using std::tuple instead of std::pair, as std::vector<std::tuple<type1, type2,.. typen>> m_types`

---

It is a good idea, although you are not profiting from polymorphism. I understand you cannot change type1 and type2 classes, but you can wrap a class around them that suits your need:

(not tested)

```
class TypeWrap
{
public:
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};

class Type1Wrap : public TypeWrap
{
private:
    Type1 m_type;
public:
    void execute(){ m_type.execute(); }
};

class Type2Wrap : public TypeWrap
{
private:
    Type2 m_type;
public:
    void execute(){ m_type.execute(); }
};
```

And then use a `vector<TypeWrap*> m_types` which will allow you to call `m_types[0]->execute();`

As a side note its bad practice (in a general sense) to use new operators directly, other options such as unique_ptr or shared_ptr are better if you need to allocate dynamically, or simply use `Type1Wrap type; m_types.push_back(&type);` to get a pointer to the object, but make sure to keep the object alive!

Comment: I actually wanted to push both type together : `m_types.push_back(type1, type2);`

Comment: you mean as a pair? given your comment `Another way is also to use std::vector<std::pair <type1, type2>> but since I might have type3 too so this still won't work for me.` you want something like m_types.push_back(type1, type2, ..., type n) right? The number of types in the same vector is always the same? Or does it change from one push_back to the other?

Comment: It remains same for one specific vector  lets say m_types takes three different types of four parameters`m_types.push_back(type1, type2, type3, type3);`

Comment: then you could template it to the types using std::tuple instead of std::pair, as `std::vector<std::tuple<type1, type2,.. typen>> m_types`

Comment: I think tuple was what I was looking for .. thank you Martin