# Vector of Eigen tensors with different ranks

Tags: c++, tensorflow, eigen, eigen3

My question: Is it possible to create a vector of Eigen tensors with different ranks?

My goal is to be able to create a vector that contains objects whose types take values among `Eigen::MatrixXd, Tensor3d, Tensor4d,..., Tensor10d` (defined below). The objects can have different types.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>

typedef Eigen::Tensor< double , 3 > Tensor3d;
typedef Eigen::Tensor< double , 4 > Tensor4d;
typedef Eigen::Tensor< double , 5 > Tensor5d;
typedef Eigen::Tensor< double , 6 > Tensor6d;
typedef Eigen::Tensor< double , 7 > Tensor7d;
typedef Eigen::Tensor< double , 8 > Tensor8d;
typedef Eigen::Tensor< double , 9 > Tensor9d;
typedef Eigen::Tensor< double , 10 > Tensor10d;

class MyClass
{
private:
    std::vector< TensorXd > Tensors;
public:
    MyClass();
};
```

Comment: Maybe that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461869/c-push-multiple-types-onto-vector , however this is somewhat ugly.

Comment: @Aziuth Thanks, I will give it a try but still looking for a more elegant and transparent solution.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged this question [[tensorflow]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow), I assume that you are using `Eigen::Tensor` as part of a TensorFlow program. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13462096/3574081) to which [Aziuth pointed in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534059/vector-of-eigen-tensors-with-different-ranks#comment72204390_42534059) suggests using a wrapper class to hold the tensors, and fortunately TensorFlow comes with its own wrapper class:  [`tensorflow::Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor).

You can create a `std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor>`, use TensorFlow's allocator to allocate memory for the different tensors, and access the wrapped `Eigen::Tensor` objects using the [`tensorflow::Tensor::tensor()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor#tensor_18) method.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @mrry. Unfortunately I'm not using Eigen::Tensor in TensorFlow but in pure C++. I tagged 'tensorflow' because I thought Tensorflow people are also very familiar with Eigen::Tensor. Sorry if that created confusion (but I think your answer will be very useful for Tensorflow users, too!).

Comment: Alas! You'll probably need to implement something similar... perhaps the code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a230417c58c258b2417225c739a1e5f0890491e6/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h) would be easy to cut down for your purposes....

Comment: Thanks, @mrry! That Tensorflow code is very useful. Let me spend some time figuring out how to use it.