# How do you create a vector of function pointers that can take different arguments?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to learn how to store functions (or rather pointers to functions) in std::vector. I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void x(int i)
{
    std::cout << "x is " << i << std::endl;
}

void y(int i, int j)
{
    std::cout << "y is " << i << " and " << "j" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<void(*)(int)> V;

    V.push_back(x);

    V[0](1);

    return 0;
}
```

This works perfectly but the problem is that I can't push_back function y into the same vector since it takes 2 integers instead of one.

What should I do to store both functions in the same vector?

Comment: How do want expect to use your vector afterward ? Who will remember/check that `v[0]` should be called with 1 arg whereas `v[42]` with 2 ?

Comment: If you want different signatures, use different containers.

Comment: I added an answer with example code, how you can achieve what you want. If you desire this approach is up to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no good way to do what you want, but you can do it.

Write an augmented variant (std or boost or hand rolled tagged typesafe union) that supports implicit cast-from with exception if you get the type wrong (feel free to support conversion between types if desired).  Call this `poly_arg<Ts...>`

Write a type eraser that takes an arg type as a template parameter.  It then takes a function pointer at construction, and type erases calling it with a vector of just the right length of arguments.  (Or a function object and an arg count range).  It then has a vararg `operator()` that forwards its arguments into a vector of its arg type, then tries to call using the above type erasure.  If the wrong number of arguments is passed, it throws an exception.  Call this `vararg_func<T>`.

Store a vector of `vararg_func<poly_arg<int, double, std::string>>` (list of 3 types is just an example).  This can store `void(*)(int)` and `void(*)(int,int)` and `void(*)(std::string, double, int)` and `void(*)()` etc, and you can invoke it.  If you get the argument count wrong, you get an exception (from vararg func).  If you get an argument type wrong, exception (from poly arg).  If you pass an incompatible function pointer, compile error at push_back (which is great!)

If you only need to support `int` args you can skip `poly_arg` and store `vararg_func<int>` instead.

I think this is a bad plan.

You very very rarely want to treat functions with different numbers and types of arguments uniformly.  The few legitimate cases are best handled with two coupled type erasing systems (like efficient massive customization point tables with non-uniform signatures) that hide the type unsafety internally.

Instead this plan matches your requirements, which forces type unsafety in its interface and pollutes your code with "dunno, maybe it will work" calls.

If you want help implementing those type erasers, realize that I both know how to write them and how they solved your problem and in my opinion they are a really bad idea.  If that fails to deter you, go and learn about type erasure in C++ and value-type polymorphism and how `std::function` works.  Try to write a toy `std::function`.  Play with a "view-only" and "move-only" version.  Try a zero-allocation with bounded function object size.  That should take a few weeks or years.

Now write some more simple cases, like printing to an ostream.  Get good enough at it.  At which point `vararg_func` shoukd be challenging but doable; try it.  If it fails, ask SO to help, including your attempt.

`poly_arg` should be easy in comparison.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is neither possible nor reasonable. It's not possible because function pointers are typed, and a pointer to a `void(int, int)` is a different type from a pointer to a `void(int)`. `vector` is a *homogeneous* container; all of its elements must be the same type. And the two types are unrelated; you cannot cast the pointer to one type into a pointer to another and expect calling it to work.

The best you can do is use a `variant` of pointers to different function types. Now, I have no idea how you would *call* those functions, since the different types take different parameter lists. How could you call it through a `visit`or functor? Do you have enough parameters to forward to the function in question? If not, then what's the point?

Unless you know a priori that index X in the list has a specific parameter list, and you have those parameters to pass to it, then there is no effective way to call it. And if you do know that, then what you probably want is a `tuple` or `struct` of function pointers, not a runtime container of them.

Comment: What about using a `void` pointer as the function parameter.  This is how Windows allows passing data to a thread.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Using a `void*` to do what? You still have to know which type to cast it back to.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::variant` if you have access to C++17:

```
#include <variant>

std::vector<std::variant<void(*)(int), void(*)(int, int)>> V;

V.push_back(x);
V.push_back(y);
```

But this gets messy real fast (if you want to add even more function types etc) and since there are different parameter types and amounts there's no sure way to uniformly call them from out of the vector unless you also store their type information and `std::get` the correct variant.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, i would recomend using [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) over function pointers. They are more generic and can be filled with a function pointer, function object or lambda expression. The typical useage looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>


struct Funktor { // This is a callable class/object
    void operator()() {
        std::cout << "Funktor called." << std::endl;   
    }
};

void function() { // Normal function
    std::cout << "Function called." << std::endl;
};

int main()
{

    std::function<void()> lambdaFunction = [](){ std::cout << "lambda function executed." << std::endl;}; // And a lambda expression (fancy way to write a function where you need it)

    std::function<void()> functionPointer = &function;
    std::function<void()> callableObject = Funktor();

    //This is the way you call functions with a std::function object, just like with a normal function
    lambdaFunction(); 
    functionPointer();
    callableObject();

    return 0;
}
```

But this does not solve your problem of storing functions with different arguments in a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Since they have a differen signature you have to treat them as if they are different types. Like `int` and `std::string`.

To store elements with different types, the STL offers [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple). You can use this one to achieve your goal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>


int main()
{

    // std::tuple takes multiple template arguments. Each corresponds to one element in the tuple
    std::tuple<
        std::function<void()>,
        std::function<void(int)>
    > functionTuple;

    // To access a element of the tuple we call std::get<i> on the tuple
    // This will return a reference to the element in the tuple and we
    // can overwrite it with whatever we want
    std::get<0>(functionTuple) = [](){
        std::cout << "Function without arguments." << std::endl;
    };

    std::get<1>(functionTuple) = [](int arg){
        std::cout << "Function without int as argument. Arg = " << arg << std::endl;
    };

    // We use std::get to get the function and the call it.
    // The the trailing '()' and '(5)' are the actual function calls,
    // just like in the example above
    std::get<0>(functionTuple)();
    std::get<1>(functionTuple)(5);

    // You can also use std::get<...> with a type as argument.
    // Have a look in the docs. Its a very nice feature of tuples
    return 0;
}
```

And if you want to achieve both, different arguments and multiple functions, you can combine `std::tuple` and `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::tuple<
        std::vector<std::function<void()>>,
        std::vector<std::function<void(int)>>
    > functionTuple;

    // We use push_back in this example, since we deal with vectors.
    std::get<0>(functionTuple).push_back([](){
        std::cout << "Function without arguments." << std::endl;
    });

    std::get<1>(functionTuple).push_back([](int arg){
        std::cout << "Function without int as argument. Arg = " << arg << std::endl;
    });

    std::get<1>(functionTuple).push_back([](int arg){
        std::cout << "Another function without int as argument. Arg = " << arg << std::endl;
    });

    std::get<0>(functionTuple).front()();
    int i = 5;
    // And we use foreach, to loop over all functions which take one integer as argument
    for(auto& f :  std::get<1>(functionTuple)) {
        f(i);
        i += 5;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

That all beeing said, I will add a word of caution. Function pointers/objects and lambdas are only one tool. They are very flexible and powerful and because of this can lead you into a rabbit hole of unexpected behaviour and errors. If you do not plan to write very generic algorithms and go deep into template metaprogramming, this tool is most likely not the best to do the job. Going for different solutions like the [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) can make your life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to alter the signature of 'x' to match that of 'y', by adding an additional int parameter that could be ignored by the body of x.

Answer (score 0):

Easy.  Place the arguments into a structure or base class.

If you use a pointer to a base class, you can expand the genericity.

An old fashioned method is to pass a `void` pointer and have the function cast it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you cannot push different pointer to function of different signatures into a vector as long as you cannot push different objects of different types into a vector.

```
class A{};
class B{};

A aObj;
B bObj;
std::vector<class A> vecA;

vecA.push_back(aObj); // ok
vecA.push_back(vecB); // error
```

- Push only objects with the same type as your vector instance require:

  ```
  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include <iostream>
  #include <vector>


  void    Foo()  { std::cout << "Foo()" << std::endl; }
  void    Foo2() { std::cout << "Foo2()" << std::endl; }

  int     Bar(float) { std::cout << "Bar(float)" << std::endl; return 0; }
  double  Baz(int, int) { std::cout << "Baz(int, int)" << std::endl; return 0;    }



  int main(){
      std::system("color 1f");


      typedef void(*pFunc1)();
      typedef int(*pFunc2)(float);
      typedef double(*pFunc3)(int, int);

      pFunc1 pFn1 = Foo;
      pFunc1 pFn2 = Foo2;
      //pFunc1 pFn3 = Bar; // error here I guess you k now why

      std::vector<pFunc1> pvcFunc1;
      std::vector<pFunc2> pvcFunc2;
      std::vector<pFunc3> pvcFunc3;


      pvcFunc1.push_back(pFn1);
      pvcFunc1.push_back(pFn2);

      for (int i(0); i < pvcFunc1.size(); i++) {
          pvcFunc1[i]();

  }




      std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
      std::cin.get();
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't do that.
I can't tell you whether using both functions in one vector is possible or not -- I'm pretty sure it isn't.

You should instead make a class and use a vector of objects.

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461869/c-push-multiple-types-onto-vector for pushing multiple data types.