# what is the use of union in c?

Tags: c, unions

I read this link [what-is-the-point-behind-unions-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671796/what-is-the-point-behind-unions-in-c)
But this answer doesn't look enough to me.

Can I have more explanations about uses of unions.
I don't want any memory related examples like, this will take max 4 bytes (float occupy 4 bytes ).

```
union un{
    char ch;
    int iNum;
    float fNum;
};
```

So my question is,

**what exactly the use of union?**

**why we need this?**

Please help me, its confusing me.
Thanks.

Comment: Please search before posting questions...

Comment: The accepted answer mentions _variant datatype_. In which isn't it enough? An example? A stack data structure.

Comment: @Dayalrai...thanks a lot !

Comment: The truth is, we don't 'need' unions.  They are useful for saving memory, but if you didn't care about saving memory you could replace every union with a struct and get similar logical behavior.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Unions are useful for type-punning, which cannot be emulated with your suggestion of replacing `union` by `struct`. I think the type-punning use of unions was official in C90 (I am not a specialist of C90), and it was made official again in C99TC3 (footnote 82) and in C11.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I agree, but type-punning can also be achieved via other means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the two most common uses for a union are:

- To implement your own [Variant type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type), a `union` gives you the ability to represent all the varying types without wasting memory. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4789053) gives a good example.
- [Type punning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) but I would read [Understanding Strict Aliasing](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html) as well since there are many cases where `type punning` is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Although in practice most compilers support type punning through a union.

Answer (score 1):

It's good if you have a variable which can be *either* a `char`, *or* a `int`, *or* ...

It's often used inside structures that contain the actual type of the union. Often used by parsers to return a token from the lexer. Something like:

```
struct token
{
    int token_type;

    union
    {
        char  *s;  /* For string or keyword tokens */
        double f;  /* For floating point tokens */
        long   i;  /* For integer tokens */
    } token_value;
};
```

In the above structure, the used member in the `token_value` member depends on the `token_type` member.

---

Unions can also be used by misusing the data in the union, where you set one member of the variable and read another. This can, for example, be used to convert a floating point number to a series of bytes.

Like

```
union data
{
    char data[sizeof(double)];
    double value;
};
```

By setting the `value` member, you can read the separate bytes of the `double` value without typecasting or pointer arithmetic. This is technically implementation defined behavior, which means that a compiler may not allow it. It is very commonly used though, so all current compilers allow it.

Comment: C99TC3's footnote 82 makes it clear that type-punning through an union belongs to the *implementation-defined* category rather than the *undefined behavior* category.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Ah, okay. Rephrased my answer for that.