# What is the reason for naming unions?

Tags: c++, c++14, unions

Why name a union if the compiler always treats the object as anonymous, regardless as to whether or not the union is named?

My implementation looks like this:

```
typedef struct _DMessageHeader {
    union _msgId {
        unsigned char ucMsgId;
        unsigned short usMsgId;
        unsigned long ulMsgId;
        unsigned long long ullMsgId;
    } msgId;
} DMSG_HDR, *PDMSG_HDR;
```

I'd like to be able to access it like this, but the compiler throws an error:

```
PDMSG_DESC ptMsg->hdr.msgId = id_in;
```

It only allows me to directly access the union member like this:

```
PDMSG_DESC ptMsg->hdr.msgId.ucMsgId = id_in;
```

Any thoughts as to why this is, or how I may access the union by name?

Comment: What is the type of `id_in`? Why do you expect to be able to assign a thing of one type to a thing of a different type?

Comment: Those typedefs were never needed in C++, not even in C++98 and still not in C++14. `_D` is plain wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why would you use union in this case at all.
Please note that the size of the struct is 8 bytes (size of long long) on my 64bit machine.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
typedef struct _DMessageHeader {
    union _msgId {
        unsigned char ucMsgId;
        unsigned short usMsgId;
        unsigned long ulMsgId;
        unsigned long long ullMsgId;
    }  msgId;
} DMSG_HDR, *PDMSG_HDR;

int main( int argc , char ** argv, char ** env)
{
    cout<<"sizof DMessageHeader"<<sizeof(DMSG_HDR)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If all you store in union msgid is a single id of varying length (1 - 8) bytes depending on your architecture) and you have no memory constrains rewrite your struct as following:

```
typedef struct _DMessageHeader {
unsigned long long msgId;
} DMSG_HDR, *PDMSG_HDR;
DMSG_HDR hdr;
hdr.msgId = id_in;
```

Also I suggest reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788965/when-would-anyone-use-a-union-is-it-a-remnant-from-the-c-only-days) thread for thorough discussion about using unions in C++.

Comment: Although this addresses a problem in the post, it does not answer the question, and should not be marked as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Its a type thing. The compiler can't convert an int something to a union.
You can however overload the "=" operator to do it.

Answer (score -1):

There can be various reasons:

- There are restrictions in original C compiler which doesn't allow anonymous unions. In other words the structure may be used by both C and C++ programs.
- You may want to work with whole union (moving, assigning etc.) and this allows you to define the variable of such types.

Answer (score -1):

Because you're not using an anonymous union in your example. You've given your union member of your struct a name, `msgId`, and it has members. You can't assign directly to the union itself, you have to assign to a member of the union.

An anonymous union would be as follows:

```
union {
    int i;
    char c;
};
i = 1;
```

or

```
struct s 
{
    int i1;
    union {
        int i2;
        char c2;
    };
};

s s1.i2 = 5;
```

The union in struct s has no name, and it's members are accessed directly.

**ETA:**

Assuming your variable `id_in` is an `unsigned char` since you assign it to the unsigned char member in the example that works, why would you expect this to work?

```
PDMSG_DESC ptMsg->hdr.msgId = id_in;
```

`ptMsg->hdr.msgId` is not of type `unsigned char` nor is it an implicitly convertible type. `ptMsg->hdr.msgId` is of type `_DMessageHeader::_msgId`.

"A union is a special class type that can hold only one of its non-static data members at a time." (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) It's a class type and you've defined no conversion operators or constructors. Of course it won't allow the assignment.

Comment: I don't want an anonymous union.  I want to be able to reference the union by name, not it's members, since its members all occupy the same memory space anyways.  Coding is more complex if I have to reference each member by name, rather than a common shared reference to the union name.

Comment: Then why are you talking about anonymous unions? Nothing about your example shows the compiler treating your union as anonymous. It shows the compiler refusing to assign a thing of one type to a thing of another type.