# C++ reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, memory, reinterpret-cast

In running this program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
char *name = "abc";
int i = reinterpret_cast<int>(name);
std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

I got the following output:

`4202656`

What does this number represent? Is it a memory address? But, memory address of what? Isn't "abc" stored as an array of characters in memory?

Thanks.

Comment: The reinterpret_cast operator produces a value of a new type that has the same bit pattern as its argument. Which compiler are you using ? g++ gives an error for the casting.

Comment: @DumbCoder. When I type `char *name = "abc";`, I get the **same** output

Answer (score 4):

It is undefined. sizeof(int) might not be equal to sizeof(char*). I'm not sure if strict aliasing rules apply here as well.

In practice however, assuming their sizes are indeed equal (most 32-bit platforms), 4202656 would represent the address of the first character in the array. I would do this more cleanly this way:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
   const char *name = "abc"; // Notice the const. Constant string literals cannot be modified.
   std::cout << static_cast<const void*>(name) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is probably the address of the character 'a'.
Though I don;t think this is guaranteed (i.e. an int may not be long enough to hold the address).

Comment: York. When I type char *name = "abc";, I get the same output

Comment: @user588855: Don't understand your comment. That's the same as your code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at the question: [casting via void* instead of using reinterpret_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863069/casting-via-void-instead-of-using-reinterpret-cast)

The short answer is that it could be anything at all.

Comment: The standard does say. The result should be unsurprising to somebody that understands the underlying memory architecture. <quote>[ Note: it is intended to be unsurprising to those who know the addressing structure of the underlying machine. — end note ]</quote>

Answer (score 0):

This the memory address of the first character of "abc", so "a". Because an array is a pointer who point to the first value of the array.
If you do `cout << *(name++)` normaly "b" is printed.

So when cast `name`, you try to cast the adress who point to "a"